# VBA Fixing Overflowing Row

Tags: vba

I am super new to VBA. I am working on a problem where I am looping and creating a sentence, but I am having a problem with an overflowing row. Can you explain where i went wrong?

```
Sub clue()
Dim name, room, weapon As String
Dim can, dag, lead, rev, rop, wre, total, least As Double
Dim row As Integer


Cells(1, 1).Activate
cam = 0
dag = 0
lead = 0
rev = 0
rop = 0
wre = 0
row = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

name = ActiveCell.Value
room = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
weapon = ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value


Cells(row, 3).Value = name & " in the " & room & " with the " & weapon & "."

If weapon = "Candlestick" Then
    can = can + 1
End If
If weapon = "Dagger" Then
    dag = dag + 1
End If
If weapon = "Lead Pipe" Then
    lead = lead + 1
End If
If weapon = "Revolver" Then
    rev = rev + 1
End If
If weapon = "Rope" Then
    rop = rop + 1
End If
If weapon = "Wrench" Then
    wre = wre + 1
End If
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Activate
row = row + 1
Loop

total = can + dag + lead + rev + rop + wre
Cells(2, 6) = can
Cells(3, 6) = dag
Cells(4, 6) = lead
Cells(5, 6) = rev
Cells(6, 6) = rop
Cells(7, 6) = wre

Cells(2, 7) = can / total
Cells(3, 7) = dag / total
Cells(4, 7) = lead / total
Cells(5, 7) = rev / total
Cells(6, 7) = rop / total
Cells(7, 7) = wre / total

least = 1000000000
If can < least Then least = can
If dag < can Then least = dag
If lead < dag Then least = lead
If rev < lead Then least = rev
If rop < rev Then least = rop
If wre < rop Then least = wre

Cells(10, 5) = least
End Sub
```

I am trying to print out a sentence on a row using certain inputs, but as the inputs change I want to print the next sentence on the next row (hence the row=row+1) but it keeps saying that there is an "overflow" problem and i need to change something but I don't know why. Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: Define row as Long Data Type `Dim row As Long` will solve it.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the very top of the module - you've declared `can` as a variant and set a value to `cam`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an overflow once you have read 32K rows

and it happens because you declared your `row` variable as `integer`.

Change it to `long` and you will be able to work on 2 billions rows

```
Dim row As Long
```

Try to remember this :

```
Byte        between 0 and 255.
Integer     between -32,768 and 32,767.
Long        between – 2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.
Currency    between -922,337,203,685,477.5808 and 922,337,203’685,477.5807.
Single      between -3.402823E38 and 3.402823E38.
Double      between -1.79769313486232D308 and 1.79769313486232D308.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Row` returns a `Long`, not an `Integer`

Note that 
`Dim name, room, weapon As String`
only defines `weapon` as `string`, the rest is `variant`.
The correct syntax is
`Dim name as string, room as string, weapon As String`

Answer (score 0):

I liked the "game" purposed question and, since you declare yourself "a super new to VBA", I think it can help you the following refactoring of your initial code

```
Option Explicit

Sub clue()

Dim can As Long, dag As Long, lead As Long, rev As Long, rop As Long, wre As Long, row As Long
Dim weapon As String
Dim roomsRng As Range, areaRng As Range, roomsReportRng As Range, finalStatsRng As Range, leastStatsRng As Range ' these are useful range variable. you'll set them and use to avoid loosing control over what you're actually handling

' here follows a section dedicated to setting relevant "ranges". this helps a lot in avoiding loosing control over what you're actually handling
With ActiveSheet 'always explicitly qualify which worksheet do you want to work with. "ActiveSheet" is the currently active one, but you may want to qualify 'Worksheets("MySheetName")'
    Set roomsRng = .Range("A1:A" & .cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row) 'set roomsRng range as the one collecting activesheet cells in column "A" down to the last non empty one
    Set roomsRng = roomsRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) 'select only non blank cells of "roomsRng" range (skip blanks)

    Set roomsReportRng = .cells(1, 3) ' set the range you start writing rooms report from
    Set finalStatsRng = .Range("F2") ' set the range you'll start writing final stats from
    Set leastStatsRng = .Range("E10") ' set the range you'll write the least found weapon number in
End With

For Each areaRng In roomsRng.Areas 'loop through all "Areas" of "roomsRng" range cells: an "Area" is a group of contiguous cells
    Call WriteRoomsReport(areaRng.cells, roomsReportRng, row, weapon) 'write room report
    Call UpdateWeaponsStats(weapon, can, dag, lead, rev, rop, wre) ' update weapons statistics
Next areaRng

Call WriteFinalStats(can, dag, lead, rev, rop, wre, finalStatsRng, leastStatsRng) ' write final statistics

End Sub



Sub WriteRoomsReport(roomCells As Range, reportCell As Range, row As Long, weapon As String)
Dim arr As Variant 'it'll be used as an array, see below

arr = Application.Transpose(roomCells) 'initialize the Variant as an array, filling it up with "roomCells" range content

reportCell.Offset(row).Value = arr(1) & " in the " & arr(2) & " with the " & arr(3) & "." 'write the report line

weapon = arr(3) ' store the weapon value to pass back to calling sub

row = row + 1 'update the row for subsequent use

End Sub



Sub UpdateWeaponsStats(weapon As String, can As Long, dag As Long, lead As Long, rev As Long, rop As Long, wre As Long)

' use "Select Case" pattern to avoid multiple and unuesful If-then repetition
' once a "case" is hit, its correspondant statements will be processed and then control passes to the statement following the "End Select" one
Select Case weapon
    Case "Candlestick"
        can = can + 1
    Case Is = "Dagger"
        dag = dag + 1
    Case "Lead Pipe"
        lead = lead + 1
    Case Is = "Revolver"
        rev = rev + 1
    Case "Rope"
        rop = rop + 1
    Case Is = "Wrench"
        wre = wre + 1
End Select

End Sub



Sub WriteFinalStats(can As Long, dag As Long, lead As Long, rev As Long, rop As Long, wre As Long, finalStatsRng As Range, leastStatsRng As Range)

Dim total As Long, least As Long
Dim weaponArr As Variant

total = can + dag + lead + rev + rop + wre
weaponArr = Array(can, dag, lead, rev, rop, wre)
With finalStatsRng.Resize(6) ' select a range of 6 cells in one clolumn, starting from the passed "finalStatsRng" range and resizing it up to enclose the subsequent 5 cells below it
    .Value = Application.Transpose(weaponArr) ' fill the selected range (using ".Value" property of the "Range" object) with the "array" technique
    With .Offset(, 1) ' shift one column to the right of selected range
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/" & total ' write in all cells a formula that takes the value form the adjacent cell and divide it by the "total" variable value
        .Value = .Value ' have formulas replaced with values. you can comment this and cells will remain with formulas (they show the resulting values, but if you select one of them you'll see a formula in the formula ribbon of Excel UI
    End With
End With

leastStatsRng.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(weaponArr) 'get the minimum value of all passed values calling the "MIN" function (which belongs to "WorksheetFuncion" object of the "Application" object -Excel) over the array filled with weapon countings

End Sub
```

the above code pattern has the following aims:

- break code into specific functions or subs

  to let you both better control the flow of your code by means of the "main" sub (that should be a sequence of statements like "Call DoThis()", "Call  DoThat()" , ...) and concentrate on specific subs/functions to handle specific job

  thus leading to a much more easily maintainable and "debuggable" code
- use only some (out of the many) relevant VBA and Excel VBA techniques, like using `Range` object (see `Resize()`, `Offset()`, `End()`, `SpecialCells()` methods), Arrays (via `Variant` type variable), `WorksheetFunction` object.

  of course you'll need to study all of those techniques (and many others!) exploiting such resources as SO itself,  MSDN site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861528.aspx) and many others you easily get in the web just googling a significant issue

as a final (and sad) note, I must warn you: building a game is something that would eventually lead towards "true" OOP, like VBA is not.

should "building games" be your true aim, then you'd better switch immediately to some true OOP language, like C#, and correspondent IDE, like Visual Studio (whose Community Edition version is currently free)